# Why are directories I create owned by root:myNonPrimaryUserGroup?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Ubuntu (WSL) user `foo` used to have primary group `foo` but I changed this to `root`. Still, when I `sudo mkdir /bar` the directory is owned by `root:foo` and not by `root:root`. Why?

```
[foo@mymachine]$ groups
root adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lxd
[foo@mymachine]sudo mkdir /bar
[foo@mymachine]$ ls / | grep bar
drwxrwxr-x  1 root foo    512 Jun 14 17:40 bar/
```

---

### UPDATE - This is a WSL/Ubunto Issue

I have just tried to reproduce the issue in CentOS and I can't.

I created `b` directly as myself (it's correctly owned by `foo:root`) and when I did `sudo mkdir c` this was also correctly owned by `root:root`.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 foo    root     6 Jun 15 14:30 b/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     6 Jun 15 14:31 c/
```

However, in WSL Ubuntu 16 the problem is definitely there:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 foo  root   512 Jun 15 14:34 b/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root foo    512 Jun 15 14:34 c/
```

Comment: As user `foo`, can you run two commands : `ls -ld /` `id` ?

Comment: `id` => `uid=1000(foo) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),4(adm),27(sudo),109(netdev),110(lxd)...`

Comment: `ls -ld /` => `drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 512 Jun 14 17:40 //`

Comment: I'm out of ideas as well. Maybe it's a problem of cache, have you rebooted your machine ? I have WSL/debian, I don't have this problem.

Comment: I have run your commands on WSL Ubuntu20 but I'm not getting your result. It may be a problem of WSL Ubuntu16.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -g root mkdir bar`

`-g` allows to choose the group in [sudo command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Comment: But where is "foo" coming from??

Comment: If you print "etc/group" you should see all the groups. Otherwise, try to run "groups foo".

Comment: What I mean is: When *I* create a file - surely it should be owned by ME and MY PRIMARY GROUP. I am not even in the foo group.